# A good choice to find solutions of ODE

Tags: differential-equations

In order to rephrase the [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17790/dsolve-parametric-system-problem).
I would ask you to take a look at the following problem:

1. I have this system of ODE:
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   \dot{x}(t)= x(t)[r_1(t) -b_1(t)x(t- \tau(t)) - c_1(t)y^m(t)] &  t\neq t_k\\
   \dot{y}(t)= y(t)[- r_2(t)- b_2(t) y(t- \sigma(t)) +c_2(t) x(t) y^{m-1}(t)] & \\
   \Delta x(t_k)= x(t_k^+)- x(t_k)=d_k x(t_k) &  t=t_k\\
   \Delta y(t_k)= y(t_k^+)- y(t_k) = f_k y(t_k) &
   \end{cases}.
   $$
2. $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are discontinuous function at points $t_k$.
3. All these functions: $r_1(t), \, r_2(t), \, b_1(t), \, b_2(t), \, c_1(t),\mbox{ and } c_2(t)$ are positive and periodic  with the same period $\omega$.
4. $\tau(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$ are continuously differentiable positive periodic functions with the same period $\omega$ such that $\tau'(t) <1 \mbox{ and } \sigma'(t)<1$.
5. $m\in (0,1)$
6. $-1 < d_k \leq 0, \, -1 < f_k \leq 0$ are constants for $k=1,2, \cdots,$ such that there exists a positive integer $q$ $t_{k+q}=t_k + \omega$.

I am trying to make the right choice for these parameters to solve this with *Mathematica*.

Comment: Do $r_1(t), \, r_2(t), \, b_1(t), \, b_2(t), \, c_1(t),\mbox{ and } c_2(t)$ have the same period? Also, do you have any other boundary conditions but the discontinuities?

Comment: thank you rcollyer for your  comment to  this post. I have improved the question as you have request.

Comment: Are the $t_k$'s pre-defined or do you find them as you solve?

Comment: We assume that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are discontinous functions at points $t_k$.

Comment: Yours is not an ODE, it is a delayed differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

The following simple example indicates that such a problem cannot be solved with `NDSolve` (in V10.0.2):

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1 - x[t - (1 + Sin[t]/10)], 
  x[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 8}]
```

> NDSolve::cdelay: The method currently implemented for delay differential equations does not support delays that depend directly on the time variable or dependent variables. >>

`DSolve` ran for an hour on the same simple example without finishing before I had to abort it.  Memory usage had gotten to 1.5GB.  I would be surprised if `DSolve` could solve it, but it does not complain that it cannot.

Representing your system abstractly as $\dot X = F[X,t]$, with $X = (x,y)$, you might code up your own solver, for instance using an Euler integration scheme:

1. $t' \leftarrow \text{step}[X, t]$
2. If $t'$ is a $t_k$,
   then $X' \leftarrow X + \Delta X$,
   else $X' \leftarrow F[X, t] * (t' - t)$

As one accumulates values of $X$, one can interpolate to estimate past values, such as for $x(t- \tau(t))$.  The step function should return a discontinuity $t_k$ instead of stepping over it. Potential problems are determining the appropriate step size, estimating the error, and controlling precision loss; one might also seek out a more robust integration scheme.